# Portable typedefs for ANSI C

Tags: c, portability

I have a portable definition of types in a header of a project that i aim to compile on multiple platforms. I'm using the following typedefs:

```
#ifndef PLATFORM_H
#define PLATFORM_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE (1)
#endif

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE (0)
#endif

typedef signed char int8_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef signed int int16_t;
typedef unsigned int uint16_t;
typedef signed long int int32_t;
typedef unsigned long int uint32_t;
typedef signed long long int int64_t;
typedef unsigned long long int uint64_t;

#endif
```

This header is platform-specific, so i have a similar declaration for every platform, making sure that integers are always the same. However, in compiling, i get this:

```
conflicting types for ‘int32_t’
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:0,
                 from platform.h:5,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:196:1: note: previous declaration of ‘int32_t’ was here
```

And other errors. What might be the cause? Can i override a typedef, or check for it's existence first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error because you picked names for your `typedef`s that collide with names of types from the [`<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/basedefs/stdint.h.html) header.

Since you are looking for types that are already defined in `stdint.h`, you might as well include it on platforms that provide this header.

Comment: include stdint.h in other platforms? But what if the platform does not support C99?

Comment: @vinnylinux Since your header is platform-specific, on platforms that do not supply `stdint.h` you continue to use definitions from your own header.

Comment: Note that i'm not including stdint.h, just stdlib

Comment: After including stdint.h, i got: error: unknown type name ‘uint16_t’

Comment: I would recommend testing for the existence of those types prior to defining them, using a configuration tool like CMake or autoconf

Comment: @vinnylinux That is very, very strange: `uint16_t` is one of the six required types that absolutely must be present in any standard-compliant `stdint.h`

Comment: @vinnylinux It is very strange that inclusion of `<stdlib.h>` defined types from `<stdint.h>` - I am not sure if it is allowed to bring in types from files other than `<stddef.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<math.h>`, and `<sys/wait.h>`. It may be an issue with `<stdlib.h>` on your particular platform.